# Adjusting a correlation matrix based on one changed correlation

Tags: correlation

I have a correlation matrix that is created by historical asset returns, but I want to see how changing one of those correlations would affect the rest of the correlation matrix. How would I go through changing the correlation matrix to account for the new information?

Let's say I have 3 asset indices - Equity, US Treasury, and US Corporate Bonds. Historically, Equity Treasury correlation is 0.2, Equity Corporate is 0.4, and Treasury Corporate is 0.4 as well (I'm making these up). But, I think that in the future, Equity Treasury will be -0.2. How do I use that new information to update what the  impact to the Corporate related correlations will be?

Are there any articles that discuss this that the Stack Exchange community is aware of?

I know that given two correlations a range exists around the possible values the third in order to maintain positive definite-ness. But is there a way to arrive at a point estimate given as much information as possible is retained from the initial correlation matrix.

Right now, I'm just changing the correlation, checking eigenvalues, and if any are negative, I'm making them slightly positive, and reconstructing. Then, I iterate by resetting the changed correlation and diagonals and test again. I'm using ~10 assets for my purpose and the correlation matrix doesn't look too funky. I'd still love to know what other options people think is better. ... mine definitely has flaws.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi: Given a correlation matrix , you end up having relations between the correlations that have to remain true in order for the positive definite-ness property of the correlation matrix to remain true. There is a recent answer on dsp.stackexchange related to your question so, if you go over there and search for .... actually, let me find it and send the link. It's not exactly gonna give you an answer but it will be useful.

Comment: @markleeds I think that this link might be useful as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284877/correlation-between-three-variables-question

Comment: @emot: Here is the one I was thinking of but maybe yours is better. I'll check it out. Thanks. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81057/is-there-relationship-between-autocorrelations-rx2-and-rx1/81064#81064 To the OP: Check out grapefruitisawesome's answer at the bottom of the link above.